# GCE firewall issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, ubuntu-16.04

GCE firewall rules are not allowing me to connect to ports 3000 / 270107 after creating the rules, in some old instance I was able to connect to the 27017 but now with a new one I can't. i have deleted all projects, VMs, Rules and everything to start from scratch but nothing.

I am working with ubuntu 16.04 instances any help would be appreciated.

[image]

there is the image that shows my firewall config on GCE, vncserver is working fine, the port 5901 as I can connect to it but 3000 and 27017 or ANY other I try to open will not...

is there a limit for the 300$ trial or something?

I have a static external IP assigned which is the one I use to connect via VNC but nothing else works

Answer (score 0):

-make sure allow the related port on your instances [iptables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089038/adding-a-rule-in-iptables-in-debian-to-open-a-new-port)
   settings.

-make sure thats are relevant your instances these fields: 'source
   filters', 'source IP ranges' and 'target tags' in your [GCP firewall
   settings](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue: it seems not possible to open ports on GCE anymore except HTTP SSH and HTTPS not sure about FTP...
I tried to raise the issue and I found out there is no support on the bronze level...